# Calling JSP file from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

I am calling a Servlet from `index.jsp` using Ajax. If the result is false, I have to display an error message on `index.jsp` itself. But, if the result is true, how do I call another JSP page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, you can use [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location) to change the current location.

E.g.

```
if (result.error) {
    document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = result.error;
} else {
    window.location = 'another.jsp';
}
```